# Experience certificate for Green card

Tags: usa, greencard

I am currently working in USA with H1B VISA since from 3 years. And I am pursuing Employment Based Green Card in USA. However my employer asked me provide technical experience certificate from my previous employers. On this context I have below questions

Is it mandatory to provide technical experience letter?
What if my previous employers denied to give such letter or not available any more?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it mandatory to provide technical experience letter?

No. What is mandatory is to prove your relevant experience and expertise to justify your being employee with experience and skills that can not be matched by the available candidates who are US citizens/residents.

> What if my previous employers denied to give such letter or not available any more?

The lawyers working with your employer will suggest other methods, like notarized testimonies of ex-colleagues and clients. These however don't hold as much value and credibility as the official company letterhead, and as such may weaken your claim.